# How to run Laravel 5.2 with HTTPS without using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, https, laravel-5

I have developed an application using **Laravel 5.2**, I want to run my routes with **HTTPS**. I have tried with .htaccess its running properly but I don't want to do with **.htaccess** because I have created a sub-domain on same server and point sub-domain to a folder.

Here is my .htaccess code:

```
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

The Main Issue which I am facing is, with .htaccess redirects to **HTTPS** and my sub-domain folder is not accessible because **.htaccess** is redirecting everything to **HTTPS**.

Comment: Well then be more specific as to under what conditions you want to rewrite to HTTPS …

Comment: @CBroe i want to run a website on HTTPS that is a requirement.

Comment: I meant be more specific in your htaccess.

Comment: @CBroe I am specific, I said htaccess is working but i don't want to use htaccess

Comment: You are saying that you don’t want to use .htaccess, _“because I have created a sub-domain on same server and point sub-domain to a folder”_ – and I’m saying, that’s nonsense. Use htaccess, but _in there_ be more specific as to when you want to rewrite.

Comment: can you give me your skype id so i can discuss with you in detail
my skype id is momi_boisterous